# Matplotlibcpp for python 3.11.5 (-lpython311: No such file or directories)

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib, compiler-errors, compilation

I’m trying to set up matplotlib cpp for python 3.11 and the command to compile the code gives me an error.

Compile command: `g++ $(cat compile_config.txt) $(cat source_files.txt) -l python311 -o calculator`

compile_config.txt:

```
-std=c++20
-O3
-Wall
-Werror
-pedantic
-g
-L/path/to/libraries
-DDEBUG
-fPIC
-march=native
-I C:\Users\.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include
-I lib\thirdParty
-I C:\Users\.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include
-L C:\Users\.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs
-DWITHOUT_NUMPY
```

source_files.txt:

```
main.cpp
headers/calculator.cpp
source/converter.cpp
source/design.cpp
source/GeneratePassword.cpp
source/operation.cpp
source/trigoOperation.cpp
source/expression.cpp
source/equations.cpp
source/statistics.cpp
source/graphics.cpp
```

error:

`C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython311: No such file or directory collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I try to import directly python311.lib in my project folder and I try a lot of combinations of compile command like:
`-lpython3.11`, `-lpython311.lib`

Unfortunately, I didn't find anything.